# Accessing the union members using the name of union

Tags: c, struct, unions

How can I access the union members which exist inside the structure?

Consider the code snippet:

```
struct Emp {

  char name[20];
   union address {

     char addr[50];
   };

};

struct Emp e;
```

Using `e`, how do I access the `addr` type without creating any union object?

Answer (score 3):

[Unnamed struct/union fields within structs/unions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) is supported in C11 and also GCC extension. If this feature is on, you can use `e.addr` directly. Note that the tag name should be empty, either.

```
struct Emp {
    char name[20];
    union {
        char addr[50];
    };
};
```

If it's not supported, you need to give the `union` a name and use `e.u.addr`.

```
struct Emp {
    char name[20];
    union address {
        char addr[50];
    } u;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the union member a name:

```
struct Emp {
   char name[20];
   union {
     char addr[50];
   } address;
};
```

Now you can access it like so:

```
struct Emp e;
e.address.addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Union should be named first and then access as

```
[struct_object_name].[union_name].[union_datamember]
```

Here,

```
struct Emp {
   char name[20];
   union {
     char addr[50];
   } Emp_address;
};

struct Emp e;
```

address it as

```
e.Emp_address.addr
```