# How to access a member of a union without naming it?

Tags: c, unions

I have some code that is very similar to the following

```
struct T {
    union {
        unsigned int x;
        struct {
            unsigned short xhigh;
            unsigned short xlow;
        };
    } x;
    /* ...repeated a handful of times for different variables in T... */
};
```

This does exactly what you'd expect: It allows me to declare a variable of type `struct T` and access either `t.x.x` or `t.x.xhigh` or `t.x.xlow`. So far so good.

However, **I would really like it if I could do just `t.x`** in the common case of wanting to access the value of the union as an `unsigned int` quantity, but retain the ability to access the high- and low-order portions independently without resorting to bit masking and shifting, and without invoking undefined behavior.

**Is that possible in C?**

**If it is possible, then what is the C syntax for the declaration?**

When I try the naiive approach of simply accessing `t.x` instead of `t.x.x`, I get warning messages like (this particular one is from a `printf()` call):

```
cc -ansi -o test -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘my_function’:
test.c:13:2: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘const union <anonymous>’ [-Wformat]
```

Using `-std=c11` instead of `-ansi` yields the same warning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22190086/2864275 looks like you need c11

Comment: The use of the compiler option `-ansi` is questionable. Why are you using 1980s style C programming? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206568/what-is-the-difference-between-c-c99-ansi-c-and-gnu-c-a-general-confusion-reg/17209532#17209532

Comment: @Lundin In this case, `-ansi` or `-std=c11` doesn't matter; both yield the same result. (I also moved away from `-ansi` rather soon after I posted this, for other reasons specifically related to more recent language constructs.) I discussed that briefly in the comments to InternetAussie's answer, but I have now also updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I believe it depends on your GCC version. `-ansi` expands to "almost C90" on older versions of GCC and "almost C11" on newer versions. It is better to use "guaranteed fully compliant C11", which is `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Adding `-Wall -Wextra` doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Lundin ...and even with all of those ( `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`), my code now compiles cleanly except for warnings that I'm not doing anything with `argc` and `argv` in my `main()` (which at this point is really just a test routine, but will almost certainly grow later on). FWIW, that's with gcc 4.7.2; not the most recent version, but seemingly recent enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anonymous unions are a thing, if you can use anonymous structs (they are both C11 features or compiler extensions).

Just as you've used a `struct` with no name to inject its members into the union's namespace, so you can also use a `union` with no name to inject its members into the enclosing namespace. Like so:

```
struct T {
    union {
        unsigned int x;
        struct {
            unsigned short xhigh;
            unsigned short xlow;
        };
    }; /* <-- no name here */

    /* ...repeated a handful of times for different variables in T... */
};
```

You just have to make sure that none of the injected names clash with other injected names or regular names that are there, otherwise it won't compile.

---

One concern though: you seem to be relying on the "fact" that `unsigned short` is half the size of `unsigned int`, and that these types are big-endian. But if that's what happens on your system, then that's fine. If not, I suggest you rethink the structure.

Comment: This looks like it's working nicely even with my GCC in `-ansi -Wall` mode, let alone `-std=c11 -Wall`, thank you!

Comment: As for your note on the relative sizes of `int` and `short`, I am aware that there is an underlying assumption hidden in plain sight there, but so far I'm just poking around. I will probably migrate this to specific types of a given size, but for now I'm just trying to see if I can get what I am doing to work at all.

Comment: Another concern is *padding*. Depending on the implementation, you may need to explicitly specify that no padding be inserted by the compiler in your inner struct. I'm not sure whether this will be handled automatically by your compiler as the natural alignment for `int` and `struct` may not be the same. You may want to look into what command line option your compiler provides or look into `#pragma pack` if you run into weird issues.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the hint, I'll keep that in mind. For the time being, keep in mind that what I posted in the question isn't *exactly* the code I actually have; there are a few differences that would be relevant for the cases raised by both you and InternetAussie, but none that were relevant *to the question I was asking* which was about accessing a member of the type.

Comment: For gcc, unnamed unions were a compiler extension before C11. Note that there was a bug involving use of designated initializers with unnamed unions; [here is a bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10676), and [here is an answer I gave to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43103933/6879826). In some cases, extra braces were needed to make designated initializers work, but this was finicky, and did not always work. The fix was supposed to have occurred in gcc 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, but still allowing to use the union name, for example to use `sizeof()` on it, or to allow a `memcpy()` copy, is to use a [Linux kernel method (2021 patch)](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-block/patch/20210727205855.411487-5-keescook@chromium.org/#24350629) to define a struct/union as both named and unnamed :

```c
#define _union_ddef(name, list...)  \
    union {                         \
        union { list };             \
        union { list } name;        \
    }
```

The macro above creates an `union` containing two unions (one unnamed, one named with the `name` parameter).
`list` parameter is the union elements you want, same as you would do with a *normal* union definition.

For example, in your case, you could define `struct T` as:

```c
struct T {
    _union_ddef(u,                             // name for the named union
                unsigned int x;                // The union elements
                struct {
                    unsigned short xhigh;
                    unsigned short xlow;
                };
        );
    /* ...repeated a handful of times for different variables in T... */
};
```

Obviously, you cannot use the same name for union and union members, and avoid any other "clash" in naming. I did replace above the former `x` union name with `u`.
The pre-processor will replace `T` definition with:

```c
struct T {
    union {
        union {                                   /* here with no name */
            unsigned int x;
            struct {
                unsigned short xhigh;
                unsigned short xlow;
            };
        };
        union {                                   /* and here with a name */
            unsigned int x;
            struct {
                unsigned short xhigh;
                unsigned short xlow; };
        } u;
    };
};
```

All put together, you can use your union with or without its name. Full code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define _union_ddef(name, list...)  \
    union {                         \
        union { list };             \
        union { list } name;        \
    }

struct T {
    _union_ddef(u,
                unsigned int x;
                struct {
                    unsigned short xhigh;
                    unsigned short xlow;
                };
        );
    /* ...repeated a handful of times for different variables in T... */
};

int main()
{
    struct T s;
    /* Then, you can access x with or without the union name */
    s.x   = 42; printf("x=%u\n", s.u.x);
    s.u.x = 24; printf("x=%u\n", s.x);
    s.xhigh   = 422; printf("xhigh=%u\n", s.u.xhigh);
    s.u.xhigh = 224; printf("xhigh=%u\n", s.xhigh);
    /* and you can use the union name for something else */
    printf("union size=%lu\n", sizeof (s.u));
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./a
x=42
x=24
xhigh=422
xhigh=224
union size=4
```

This method (see Linux kernel patch above) can be used with structures, and may also be changed to add a struct/union tag/type as well as attributes (so that the *named* part looks like `struct TAG { LIST } ATTRS name;`).

EDIT: As discussed in comments, this method might not be seen as good practice.

Comment: As a casual code reviewer I would reject such, as it confuses other coders. How should they know that `s.x` and `s.u.x` are the same thing? One name for one thing, and no surprises! You could extend your answer to show serious use cases.

Comment: @thebusybee, does not `main()` example show exactly that ? That you can use directly the member of a union without naming it (the OP question) but also use the union name, for example with `sizeof`, which would not be possible with chosen answer ? If you have an idea on how I could improve the answer, I will happily amend it.

Comment: Well, I mean a useful use case that forces us to provide **two different** ways to the **same** value. It's clear that it is possible, but not all what is possible makes sense.

Comment: I think we don't understand each other... Again, one may want to access union/struct elements "easily" (`foo.x` instead of `foo.bar.x`), but still want to access the `bar` union/struct by itself (sizeof, start/end addresses, these kind of things, also shown in `main()`). I never said we *are forced to* use `foo.x` or `foo.bar.x`. In fact, the `sizeof` issue was a possible reason given in the first sentence of my answer).

Comment: OK. _That_ could be a good reason you might want to add: Access a single member of a structure with a shortened name, but handle the struct as a complete unit, too. But while I write this, I still feel unpleasant because of this hidden mapping. In my code I rather wont use this, out of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment. We need to think about future readers of code being irritated about this, just because they don't expect that "mechanics."

Comment: Anyway, since you answer the OP's question, please keep it. You might want to consider to add a note that this usage might not be seen as good practice.

Comment: Thanks @thebusybee. I did add a note about good practice, plus a "real world" example (Linux kernel). Please let me know if I can still improve this answer/make it clearer.